# Replace values in one column in multiple cells in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, replace

I'm trying to replace the 5th column in each cell in a cell array with the 5th column of each cell from another cell array. I made the following function, which does this but also replaces the values in all other columns with 0. How do I do this without deleting all other values from the other columns. The function is:

```
function [X]=replace_cells(cell) 
X={};
for i=1:length(cell)
   X{i}(:,[5])=cell{i}(:,[5]);
end
```

end

Comment: `X` has been initialized as an empty array. You are only copying the 5th column from each cell of `cell` into `X` so the other values can *only* be `0`. I would also highly recommend not using [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't replace the columns because the function creates `X` while it should be an input, try this function,

```
function X = replace_cells(c,X) 
for i = 1 : length(c)
   X{i}(:,5)=c{i}(:,5);
end
```

`cell` is a Matlab function don't use it as name for variables.

Comment: This doesn't do what you say it does. Arguments (if they are not handle objects) are copied into the function's workspace, which means that your function will alter a copy, not the original. If you want to fix it you should declare your function like this `function X=replace_cells(c,X)`.

Comment: There is probably a return argument missing.